# Serilog sink with MsSqlServer in a .NET Core 1.1 console app

Tags: .net-core, serilog

I am trying to implement Serilog sink for SQL Server (v. 13.0) in a .NET Core 1.1 Console App, but when I try to write in the table I define, the result is unfortunately always an empty.

I tried to follow the documentation provided in GitHub and other suggestions found in Stack Overflow but nothing could help me properly.
I am probably missing something, but what?

The code I'm trying to implement in the Main is as follows

```
        private static Serilog.ILogger _seriLogger;
        . . . . . . .
        var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();
        columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
        // Rename columns
        columnOptions.Exception.ColumnName = "Controller";
        columnOptions.Properties.ColumnName = "Action";
        // Add a custom column
        columnOptions.AdditionalDataColumns = new Collection<DataColumn>
        {
            new DataColumn { AllowDBNull = true, ColumnName = "ExtraInfo", DataType = typeof(string)}
        };

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging()
        .AddSingleton<Serilog.ILogger>(x =>
        {
            return new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\HR2014;Database=MyLog;User Id=serilogdb;Password=********;", "Logs",
                    autoCreateSqlTable: true,
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug,
                    batchPostingLimit: 1,
                    period: TimeSpan.Zero
                    /* , columnOptions: columnOptions */)
                    .CreateLogger();
        })
        .BuildServiceProvider();

        //configure logging
        serviceProvider
            .GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .AddSerilog();

        _seriLogger = serviceProvider.GetService<Serilog.ILogger>();

        _seriLogger.Debug("test");
```

I wish to point out a couple of things:

1. I don't get any compiler or run-time error;
2. The table Logs is successfully created but when I uncomment the *columnOptions* the table is not created at all and no error message is shown.

When I try

```
_seriLogger.Information("test");
```

rather than

```
_seriLogger.Debug("test");
```

I have the error message: System.StackOverflowException.